# Hide Title bar and Show Close Button in jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-dialog

I have hide title bar in  `jQuery Dialog` as below

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
```

This also hide close button in `Dialog`. But i need to show close button on `Dialog`.

How can i do this ?

Comment: @seemly tried this `$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();`

Comment: Try like this: $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('visibility', 'visible');

Comment: @PriyaSunanthan not worked

Comment: can u fiddle ur code.

Comment: @PriyaSunanthan http://jsfiddle.net/62yJ4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding the following CSS will hide the title text and style, leaving the close button in place - [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/88vSP/2/).

```
.ui-dialog-title {
    display:none;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    right:0;
}
```

However, if you want to change the style of the close button itself (as mentioned in your other question - [Arrow in Bottom of jQuery Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672942/arrow-in-bottom-of-jquery-dialog/)) then I suggest asking another question since showing the [`closeText`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeText) is *still* a problem when using a jQuery theme - see [jQuery UI Dialog - Cannot see the closeText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790724/jquery-ui-dialog-cannot-see-the-closetext)

Comment: I have added this code. but close button is display in left side. not in right side.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code where this is happening? It is on the right side in my demo.

Comment: Created [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NK2qm/2/) with my code. It is working properly. but in my pc, close button is display in left side.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691104/show-close-button-in-right-side-of-jquery-dialog) to my new question about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show the `ui-dialog-titlebar-close` class  of `dialog`

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
```

And with css (what I am doing)

```
body .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
   visibility=visible;
}
```

Comment: @Bishan can you please check that css solution ??otherwise I'l delete this post soon :)

Comment: there is no such thing as display:visible

Comment: where should i put this `css` ? on `jquery.ui.dialog.css` ?

Comment: @seemly My bad dude..sorry.Edited.Thanks for the spot.

Comment: should i put `$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();` in js file ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33543/discussion-between-suresh-atta-and-bishan)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

(Assume your close button has id #close)

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar : not(#close)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css('visibility','hidden');
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('visibility','visible');
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62yJ4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What about just set height to 0? Seemed work for my needs.

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
  height: 0;
}
```