# "Speech Balloon"-like arrow for Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

In my attempt to add arrows to my Jquery dialog boxes, I've been following the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674022/758494).

However, this solution makes use of Jquery's `ui-resizable-*` classes, but I don't want my dialog boxes to be actually resizable.

Is there another interaction I can use instead of `resizable`, or is there a way of keeping the `resizable` handles but disabling the resizable functionality?

Comment: Glad to see you got an answer (which I have already upvoted) after our quick conversation on the other question :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use `.ui-dialog` class instead, just adjust arrow positioning a bit

see working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/bV4G4/2/)

Comment: I see your example, but I'm trying to understand how that works: shouldn't the `before` and `after` of the dialog be in two different places? The `before` and `after` of `ui-resizable-*` being in the same place makes sense to me, but how does that work for an entire dialog box?

Comment: consider `before` and `after` as a standalone elements, they're absolutely positioned so can be placed anywhere, and since the dialog box itself is made `overflow:visible` they can be visible even out of it

Comment: I'll give that a shot. In my case, I want the arrow on top of the dialog box, pointing up. Also, I've removed the titlebar: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isaackleinman/E955W/)

Comment: you can make it same way for top,left,right whatewer. btw consider using [bootstrap popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers), you can include them separately, without rest of bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; extremely helpful. Browsing through a couple of those plug-ins makes a lot of my recent work superfluous!