# Show Close Button in Right side of jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-dialog

I have created a `jQuery Dialog` as in this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NK2qm/2/). It is working properly. close button is display in right side in there. but on my site, running on localhost, close button is display in left side as in below image.

[image: jQuery Dialog]

How can i solve this ?

**Close Button Style**

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">close</span>
</button>
```

Comment: In your PC? Or on your site?

Comment: on my site, running on localhost :)

Comment: @bishan, on changing this .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close from right:0; to left:0;, solved the problem in fiddle, so it may that, some other css/style is overwritting this style,

Comment: the problem could be from your css...

Comment: yes, .. abs.. it's the case of conflicting styles..

Comment: `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    left:0;
}` not working.

Comment: Can you _Right click_ -> _Inspect_ the close button and then find the `<a>` parent element of the button in Chrome. Could you copy the _Computed Style_ in the Chrome Console and paste the output into the question? The element should look something like `<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>`.

Comment: @andyb Updated post with style. there is no `<a>` tag. there is a `button` tag.

Comment: Ah, you must be using a newer version of jQuery and/or jQueryUI - as the markup for the close button changed somewhere between v1.9.2 -> v1.10.3. It still doesn't explain why the button is on the left. Can you please _Inspect_ the `<button>` and check the _Computed Style_ in the Chrome DevTools. In particular I'd like to see the `writing-mode` CSS property. Also, which browser and version are you using?

Comment: @andyb I have uploaded a `html` file with dialog. download it from [here](http://goo.gl/2mydi).

Comment: That's great - I can reproduce the problem here. Sorry I couldn't look at it earlier, I can't access dropbox from work :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference between your [example files](http://goo.gl/2mydi) and the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NK2qm/2/) is the the jsFiddle includes a jQueryUI theme which is adding some CSS rules to the `<button>`.

By adding any jQueryUI theme to your demo, it corrects the problem. For example, including:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel='stylesheet' />
```

adds the style:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: .3em;
    top: 50%;
    width: 21px;
    margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

which includes `position: absolute`. Without `position`, the `right: 0` that I added in the other question [Hide Title bar and Show Close Button in jQuery Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672445/hide-title-bar-and-show-close-button-in-jquery-dialog) has no effect, which explains why the button appears on the left, since that is where it would naturally appear in *normal flow*.

So if you are not using a [jQueryUI theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), then you need to add `position: absolute` to the **close button's** rules, like this:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you check my new question about [get values from GridView in jQuery Dialog in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803400/how-to-get-values-from-gridview-in-jquery-dialog-in-c-sharp). now i'm in a trouble since this question.

Comment: I haven't coded in `C#` for a long time but I will have a look at your question and help if I can.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility - 
The styles are conflicting. Check for the `left:` (or `right:`) CSS attributes in your html and CSS files. I think the styles for the class -

`.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close`

are conflicting.

**Edit:**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<style type="text/css">
.ui-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: .2em;
    outline: 0;
    overflow:visible;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
    display:none;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    left:0;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    background: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { border-width: 0 !important; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: right;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
    margin: .5em .4em .5em 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    background-position: 16px 16px;
}
.ui-draggable .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    cursor: move;
}
.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s::before, .ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s::after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s::before {
    border-color: #aaa transparent transparent transparent;
    top: 2px;
}
.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s::after {
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
    top: 1px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        width: 300,
        height: 'auto',
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {

            }
        }
    });
}); 
});//]]>  
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    left:0;
}` not working.

Comment: What is `result-light.css` ?

Comment: I copied your code to a `html` page and comment line for `result-light.css` style sheet and run. but still close button is in left side.

Answer (score 0):

this is css that u need change :)

http://prntscr.com/1fwgfz